# Running a Group of Rules Using StatelessKnowledgeSession

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine, rule

Using StatefulKnowledgeSession I'm able to define a filter which describes the rules I want to execute:

```
session.fireAllRules(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(ruleName));
```

But I couldn't find a way to do same thing using StatelessKnowledgeSession:

```
cmds.add(CommandFactory.newFireAllRules());
ExecutionResults results = session.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));
```

CommandFactory.newFireAllRules() can take *int max* and *String outIdentifier* or no parameter at all.

Excessive(!) documentation of JBoss Drools doesn't help me either:

[Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/command/CommandFactory.html#newFireAllRules%28%29)

My question is whether this is possible or not.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to use a Stateless session and not an Stateful one?

Comment: Hi @Esteban. I don't want to deal with exposing session whenever I call it. Also I don't need any state in the rules. I'll just pass the facts and expect a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CommandFactory doesn't have methods for creating a FireAllRulesCommand using filters, but you can just create one yourself:

```
List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList<Command>();
cmds.add(CommandFactory.newInsert(new MyFact()));
cmds.add(new FireAllRulesCommand(new RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter("MyRule")));
ExecutionResults results = ksession.execute(CommandFactory.newBatchExecution(cmds));

private static class RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter implements AgendaFilter {
    private final String ruleName;
    public RuleNameEqualsAgendaFilter(final String ruleName) {
        this.ruleName = ruleName;
    }
    public boolean accept(final Activation activation) {
        return activation.getRule().getName().equals(this.ruleName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Steve. As I pointed out JBoss documentation isn't sufficient. Do you have a blog or something to check out or do you know helpful blogs/web pages about Drools?

Comment: The main blog you should track for Drools is: http://blog.athico.com/ My own blog is http://scattercode.co.uk/ but there's not much Drools (or any other!) stuff on it yet. I'm building a small example project (Spring REST API with Drools underneath) at https://github.com/gratiartis/sctrcd-payment-validation-web for which I will probably write a few blog/tutorial bits soon.

Comment: Bonus reading - Wolfgang Laun wrote a white paper on "Design patterns in production systems", which is based on Drools and which should give you some good ideas for improving your rules: https://engage.redhat.com/forms/rule-design-patterns